# what is ideal fixed thread pool size for a task in which remote API is called (timeout-30s) also includes CRUD db operation in the same?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, threadpool

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor in my spring boot app(also includes spring-data-jpa) with fixed thread pool of size 60. The thread task contains a remote api call and CRUD operations over database(SQL-server 2012).

1. What is the ideal size of pool which i can use to perform this
   operation?
2. what are the precautions i need to take while implementation?
3. Are there any chances i might run into deadlocks in database because of concurrent transactions?
4. please suggest tuning techniques if any for CRUD operations.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend below steps before you set any thread pool configuration.

1. What is the ideal size of pool which i can use to perform this
   operation?
     How much time is your thread task taking and how much is your traffic ?  This will help you to come up with an optimal thread pool size and time out setting for
   the threads in the pool.
2. what are the precautions i need to take while implementation?
   I will ensure thread has a time out setting and every external system touch point like api,database etc has a timeout setting. This will ensure your threads are gracefully timed out.
3. Are there any chances i might run into deadlocks in database because of concurrent transactions?
   Usually databases are very good at locking a record whenever write happens,but again this depends on the type of queries you are running in the database.

The question requires more information to answer effectively.

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a
Q&A site, where we reserve the answer space for answers. Please check out our
short [tour]. Could you please [edit] this to more directly address the 
question?